# Adding date difference of two dates in Sql for all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a table with two date columns as **ArrivalDate** and **DepartureDate**.
I need to calculate the total time period in hours and minutes (not **date**) of all the entries in the table . I can get the time period of a particular record via datediff but what i need is the **sum of all the date differences in my table in hours and minutes** .

What I am doing is this for getting date difference

```
set @StartDate = '10/01/2012 08:40:18.000'
set @EndDate =   '10/04/2012 09:52:48.000'

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(CONVERT(varchar(23),@EndDate,121) AS DATETIME)
-CAST(CONVERT(varchar(23),@StartDate,121)AS DATETIME),8) AS TimeDiff
```

This only gives a particular date difference . I need all the date differences in my table and then there sum.

Comment: please provide sample output!

Comment: If you simply add FROM tableName after that select statement, and change \@StartDate and \@EndDate to the date columns do you not get the desired result?

Comment: Why are you casting your variables to VARCHAR, then back to DATETIME, before subtracting one from the other?

Comment: Find the difference in seconds, then sum this if you have to, then convert the final figure to hours/minutes

Comment: @Himansz what is your desired output?

Comment: If you want continued help on Stack Overflow I would suggest you engage with the community. Once people see that you ask questions and then disappear once the answers have been given they will stop helping. I would suggest that you look at the answers provided and if any have helped then mark one as the answer. The same goes for your other questions also.

Comment: For Your Information CSL i tried adding a comment yesterday to show the sample output,but ended up getting an error

Comment: @CSl the error was related to adding a comment for a particular user only...

Comment: So are you saying that none of the answers helped you at all and you still don't have the output you want? if so edit your POST with more details don't add a comment.

Comment: All the answers are useful and much appreciated...I just wanted to inform you about the error i got while adding a comment on Stackoverflow.com..

Comment: Ok good, I am glad you got sorted, if any of the answers directly helped you here I would recommend marking it as the answer (and on one of your other questions also) - people tend to help those who do give credit where it is due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will generate the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, R.ArrivalDate, R.DepartureDate)) / 60 as TotalHours
     , SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, R.ArrivalDate, R.DepartureDate)) % 60 as TotalMinutes
 FROM TableWithDates R
```

The first column returned divides the total minutes by 60 to give you the whole number of hours. The second column returned calculates the remainder when dividing the total minutes by 60 to give you the additional minutes remaining. Combined the 2 columns give you the sum total of the elapsed hours and minutes between all of your Arrival and Departure dates.

Comment: Start and end date have to be reversed otherwise you get negative integer back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.EndDate, t.StartDate)) AS Hours,
  (
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.EndDate, t.StartDate)) - 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.EndDate, t.StartDate)) * 60
  ) AS Minutes
FROM
  YOUR_TABLE t
```

IT should do the trick.

Comment: Ummm, if two dates are 1 hour 23 minute apart, this will give 1 hour and 83 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
SELECT CAST( (SUM(DATEDIFF(mi , ARRIVALDATE , DEPARTUREDATE)))/60 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        + ':'+  
       CAST( (SUM(DATEDIFF(mi , ARRIVALDATE , DEPARTUREDATE)))%60 AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM YOURTABLE
```

this is just a pseudo code.. replace table and column names as needed..

Comment: You are converting to minutes and seconds, not hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you have long time periods int will fail in SUM. So this will work,

```
SELECT TIME / 60 AS HOURS
       ,TIME % 60 AS MINUTES
FROM (
      SELECT SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate) AS BIGINT)) AS Time
      FROM Table
     ) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @totalSeconds as numeric
SELECT @totalSeconds = sum(Datediff(ss, ArrivalDate , DepartureDate)) from tableName

SELECT @totalSeconds //displays total seconds

select CAST(@totalSeconds /3600 AS int), (CAST(@totalSeconds /60 AS int) - (CAST(@totalSeconds /3600 AS int)*60)) //converting seconds to hours & minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following

DECLARE @TotalWaitingMinutesOverall INT = (SELECT SUM(DATEPART(MI, (ISNULL(DepartureTime, GETDATE()) - ArrivalTime))) 
FROM MY TABLE

Then,
 @Hrs INT = TotalWaitingMinutesOverall /60

Then to display the time,

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Hrs) + ':' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @TotalWaitingMinutes - (@Hrs * 60)) AS TIME